# PHP Mongo - find last object in collection

Tags: php, mongodb

How would full PHP block of code look like to return last inserted object in collection? This is my function but it doesn't return proper object.

```
# Create connection instance
        $this->mongo = new MongoClient($connection_string);
        # Select database
        $this->database = $this->mongo->selectDB($database_name);

public function get_last($given_collection){
        $collection = $this->database->selectCollection($given_collection);
        $data_object = $collection->find()->sort(array("id"=>1));
        return $data_object;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$collection->find()->sort(array("_id"=>-1))->limit(1);
```

This is mongodb query working fine show data in descending order.

```
db.collection.find().sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1);
```